# Pocket door: securing lower frame?

Tags: doors, framing, pocket-door

I installed a Cox 32 Series pocket door. The [instructions](http://www.coxusa.us/03_installation/Series_32_Installation.pdf) don't mention securing the bottom of the frame to the building.

You can see the bottom of the frame is simply floating above the sub-floor. I've secured it to the floor with a few screws.

[image: Bottom of the frame]

Close angle of the bottom of the frame.

[image: Bottom of the frame floats above subfloor]

What do you recommend I use to secure the frame? Ultimately, the frame isn't very robust, is that normal for pocket doors?

Edit:
I can't find instructions for framing install of Cox doors, but I found instructions for a similar brand and they recommend screws every 16"

[image: screws bottom]

Thank you!!

Comment: thanks @isherwood i can't find any instructions from Cox, strange. And yes, no strap across the floor - it's completely open to the floor

Comment: The "every 16 inches" thing refers to the vertical frame member against the wall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pocket door frames are usually secured on the bottom through steel straps connecting the bottom rails. We can't really see them in your photos, but I suspect they're there.

If they're not, here are a few ideas. It doesn't need to be complex.

- Run long screws down through the bottom rail. You might need to pull the drywall to do this accurately. One on each side penetrating the subfloor completely would be enough.
- Run toenail screws through the bottom rails. These could go right through the drywall as long as you stay below the top of the base trim you intend to use. I'd use two on each side.
- Use L-brackets. One technique would be to mark the frame location on the floor, then spread the sides and install one leg at the frame location (ultimately under the frame), and finally fasten the other leg to the front edge of the frame. You could also just install them inside the door slot. Keep them back a few inches so they don't show.

If you're asking whether it's normal for such a frame to *not* seem very robust, they're all like that. There's virtually no load applied to the side rails, and once your drywall is installed it'll be fine.

Word to the wise: Use no longer than 1-1/4" drywall screws, and *remember to only use short nails when installing your base trim*. I've punched nails into several expensive oak doors in my day. It's not a fun discovery.

Comment: Yes! I did 1" screws for the dry wall.

Comment: The drywall is the obvious part, while it's fron-of-mind. The base trim is the part you forget as you're working around the room and it doesn't come to mind. I'd mark that area in red ink.